# What's the correct adverb for predict?

Tags: adverbs

I'm trying to figure out whether it is valid to say

> the size of ... is predictively determined

some sources on the web include predictively as a valid adverb, some don't.
And what about *predictably*?

Thank you!

Comment: *Predictably* means you can predict the outcome beforehand. The synonym is "reliably". *Predictively* means "operating in a mode of being predictive", "using predictions". You probably want the first one.

Comment: Actually you don't want an adverb at all. You want the verb. "The size of X is predicted".

Comment: @RegDwighт There's a difference between *predicting* and *predictively determining*, at least the OP's context.

Comment: "Predictively determine" is a valid phrase and widely understood in the context domains. http://www.google.com/#output=search&q=%22predictively+determine%22

Comment: What *is* OP's context? I am not seeing any context. If it is widely used and understood in his context, what is the question here?

Comment: Correction: on a second thought, I cannot *predict* which of the two words you need. More context is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a person is speaking predictively, you might say,

> "With her pronouncements Ms. Knowitall was in her usual predictive mode."

In other words, she was wont to make predictions as if she knew what would happen.

You could then say of her,

"She was speaking predictively again, which she is wont to do."

Call me old-fashioned, but I prefer putting the adverb after the verb:  complaining loudly, snoring noisily, conjecturing predictively.